# pdfcomment tikz and \tikzexternalize: not shown, without \tikzexternalize it works

Tags: tikz-pgf

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% \tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(A){Test\pdfcomment{Testcontent}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

```
 pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
```

This way a pdf is generated that contains an annotation.

If `\tikzexternalize` is uncommented the annotation is missing

How to get the annotation WITH `\tikzexternalize` (i rely on `\tikzexternalize` due to buffer size)

Comment: you can't. with tikzexternalize the picture is reinserted with includegraphics and this strips annotations. You would have to reinsert them, something which is theoretically possible, see the newpax package which does it for links, but currently there is no package yet which does it also for widget or text annotations. What could work is to move the annotation out of the picture in another one which is overlayed and not externalized.

Comment: how would i prevent parts from externalizing?

Comment: `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable` is one answer to this. Thanks!